# Pipe to File Permission Denied

Tags: bash, shell, permissions, pipe, echo

I am trying to do something similar to:

```
echo "things" >> file
```

called from a java project. Even calling this directly from a terminal yields

```
-bash: file: Permission denied
```

This is because the >> isn't directed appropriately. Alternatively, I could do

```
sudo -s 'echo "wtf" >> metrics'
```

and that works. I cannot, however, do sudo from the java project. What alternative could I use to accomplish this?
I can change the files permissions as needed, I just need to append a line to it every time the project runs.

Comment: Give the user write access to the file or indirect via a tool or daemon which runs as a user who has that.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's not because of redirection (>>).  It's because the file needs permission.  If the user on which your java program runs have enough permission to write to object named file, then it will work

Comment: The user has full permissions on that file and owns it. Even calling this directly from a terminal yields the same result. How do I need to change the permissions for it to work?

I know I can create a new file and do echo "things" >> file   and everything work.

Comment: Normally, general write permissions should be enough to append to the file. If it's not, probably you have a more complicated environment, when something else is in the way. Please specify your environment in as much as detail as you can, i.e. operating system, filesystem, mount options, usage of mandate access control systems, SELinux, extended POSIX file attributes, kernel-based virtualization, etc.